# Assigning Ecommerce Revenue Value to Existing Goal Value

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, conversions, goal-tracking, google-ads-valuetrack

Optimizing an existing AdWords - Analytics setup. Previously, a conversion goal was set up, tracking a thank you type page without a value. AdWords is using this from Analytics to measure conversion ratio.

As we wanted to add financial insights, we added ecommerce tracking on this thank you page. This works, we now get the ecommerce revenue reports.

However, this is not linked to the conversion goal value. This remains 0.

We don't want AdWords to use a new goal, as we want to keep historic conversion rate values. We simply want to assign the now newly available ecommerce per transaction revenue value, to the existing but always zero goal value.

How can we accomplish this?

Can it simply be linked in Analytics? Couldn't find this option. Google suggests to keep Goal Value blank if ecommerce tracking is enabled. But this doesn't link the two.

How can we make the goal value be the same as the ecommerce transaction revenue value ?